# DSolve and the numbering of constants of integration

Tags: differential-equations

The solution to the differential equation shown below is straightforward to find, and Mathematica gives a fine result.

```
DSolve[y''[x] == Sin[x], y[x], x]

{{y[x] -> C[1] + x * C[2] - Sin[x]}}
```

However, the constants of integration seem numbered "out of order". When solving by hand, one would likely obtain $y'(x) = \cos(x) + c_1$, then $y(x) = -\sin(x) + c_1x + c_2$, with the coefficient of $x$ being needed first.

How does Mathematica order/number the constants? Specifically, why isn't the coefficient of $x$ `c[1]`? Is it simply numbering them in the order shown in the output?

(FWIW, this isn't a big deal. Just curious.)

Comment: Messing a bit with `DSolve` and other methods which use `C` I think you are right in assuming that Mathematica labels them in the output stage in order of appearance. I strongly suspect (from writing some code using dummy indices/constants myself) that internally something like `Unique[]` is used to generate unique constants during the computation and they are only renamed in the output stage.

Comment: "When solving by hand" - this is the disconnect you have. The methods `DSolve[]` uses internally can be quite different from manual computation, and it's not unreasonable to assume that it's having to generate the necessary constants in a different order (and thus indexing) from what you would do manually.

Comment: Just renumber them, i.e., `DSolve[y''[x] == Sin[x], y[x], x] /. C[n_] :> C[3 - n]`